# No PUT post data being received

Tags: php, post, curl, put

I am sending out a PUT request to my site via PHP using cURL:

```
$data = array("a" => 'hello');
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/linetime/user/1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

I am then listening for this PUT request, but receiving no data with the request. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$putData = '';
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $s = fread($fp, 64);
    $putData .= $s;
}
fclose($fp);
echo $putData;
exit;
```

Comment: You mean you specified your script as PUT handler in your web server's configuration? For example in Apache using the [`Script`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#script) directive: `Script PUT /your/script.php`.

Comment: Try enforcing a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: @XcodeDev See my updated post below.  I think the problem is the way you are sending data, not the way you are receiving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure to specify a content-length header and set post fields as a string

```
$data = array("a" => 'hello');    
$fields = http_build_query($data)
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/linetime/user/1');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 

//important
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields))); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, I still get the same problem anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTTP client class to help send the requests.  There are several available, but I have created one (https://github.com/broshizzledizzle/Http-Client) that I can give you help with.

**Making a PUT request:**

```
<?php
require_once 'Http/Client.php';
require_once 'Http/Method.php';
require_once 'Http/PUT.php';
require_once 'Http/Request.php';
require_once 'Http/Response.php';
require_once 'Http/Uri.php';

use Http\Request;
use Http\Response;

header('Content-type:text/plain');

    $client = new Http\Client();


    //GET request
    echo $client->send(
        Request::create()
            ->setMethod(new Http\PUT())
            ->setUri(new Http\Uri('http://localhost/linetime/user/1'))
            ->setParameter('a', 'hello')
    )->getBody();

?>
```

**Processing a PUT request:**

```
//simply print out what was sent:
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'PUT':
        echo file_get_contents('php://input');

        break;
}
```

*Note that I have an autoloader on my projects that will load all those includes for me, but you may want to consider making a file that will include everything if you don't want to go down that route.*

---

**Library-less:**

```
//initialization code goes here

$requestBody = http_build_query(
    array('a'=> 'hello'),
    '',
    '&'
);

$fh = fopen('php://memory', 'rw');
fwrite($fh, $requestBody);  
rewind($fh); 

curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);  
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($requestBody));  
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true); 

//send request here

fclose($fh);
```

Note that you use a stream to send the data.

Comment: Nope, it's not. Just tested: The code works on my system, although it's clunky for not using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: could it be due to the fact that I am using MAMP?

Comment: The curl request is working perfectly, but still I am receiving no data on the other side of the request.

Comment: @XcodeDev Try using the updated code above.  I've verified that it works for myself on a localhost.

Comment: @XcodeDev Then you didn't send any input to PHP.  This is probably because you aren't sending a stream to PHP as you should be.  Posted some PHP code for doing this without a library.

Comment: What do you mean by send request here? I tried that code before and it didn't work either.

Comment: @XcodeDev `curl_exec`, most likely.  Maybe post your attempt at my code so I can see what you are messing up on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4846/discussion-between-xcodedev-and-levi-morrison)