# $_POST array is null while using PUT in cURL

Tags: php, post, curl, put

I have this code:

```
$curl = curl_init("localhost/curlexample/index.php/users/$id");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $temp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```

I'm trying to access the variables in $temp using $_POST super global but it returns null. I want to perform a PUT operation using cURL which I'm trying to achieve using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST. Now, whenever I remove CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST from the code, it works fine. Otherwise, $_POST returns null.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an alternate way to perform PUT?

I used this for reference: https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/08/30/doing-put-and-delete-with-curl-in-php/

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: I think you have to read PUT data from PHP's stdin - something like `$data = fopen('php://input');`

Comment: Actually, here's a related question that looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069737/no-put-post-data-being-received?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this post](http://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php). You need to access the data using `php://input`, like this:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post_vars); // $post_vars will get populated with the PUT variables.
```